# Android Bugsense gives Exception: “getaddrinfo: bugsense.appspot.com return error = 0x8 >>”

Tags: android, bugsense

I am using bugsense 3.4jar. I have a simple test code to generate NullPointerException.But I could not see the crash generated,so i look for the logcat of eclipse,found these logs:

```
08-05 16:30:03.967: W/BugSenseHandler(10490): Transmitting crash Exception No peer          certificate
08-05 16:30:03.973: I/System.out(10490): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:49073]
08-05 16:30:03.974: W/BugSenseHandler(10490): Transmitting crash Exception No peer    certificate
08-05 16:30:03.981: D/libc-netbsd(10490): getaddrinfo: bugsense.appspot.com  return error = 0x8 >>
08-05 16:46:27.199: W/BugSenseHandler(10660): Transmitting crash Exception No peer certificate
```

mycode:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, MYAPIKEY);
            .......
      try {
        String i = null;
        Log.e("test crashed report", i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         BugSenseHandler.sendException(e);
    }
```

someone help me? thanks!

Comment: i send email to them,they said that:"unfortunately BugSense is blocked in certain chinese subnets. Please try the useProxy() function just after initialization and try again.",after that ,i use the useProxy() function,it still does'nt work,So i change my plan,find another product that called Crittercism,it work well and free!